# If $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to x_0} g(x) = +\infty$ prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

> Consider the functions $f, g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for which holds that $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to x_0}  g(x) = +\infty$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}=0$

**Is the following proof correct?** For some $x \to x_0$ holds that $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)>0$

So it is true that $2f(x)g(x)\geq 0 \\ \Rightarrow (f(x)+g(x))^2 \geq f^2(x)+g^2(x) \\ \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \geq \dfrac{1}{(f(x)+g(x))^2} \\ \Rightarrow \dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \geq \dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{(f(x)+g(x))^2}=\dfrac{1}{f(x)+g(x)}$

But $\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}>0$ hence $\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}=\Bigg|\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}\Bigg|$

Thus $\Bigg|\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}\Bigg| \geq \dfrac{1}{f(x)+g(x)} \\  \Rightarrow \dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \geq \dfrac{1}{f(x)+g(x)} \text{OR} \dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \leq -\dfrac{1}{f(x)+g(x)} \\ \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \geq \lim_{x \to x_0}\dfrac{1}{f(x)+g(x)} \text{OR} \lim_{x \to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \leq -\lim_{x \to x_0}\dfrac{1}{f(x)+g(x)} \\ \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \geq 0 \text{OR} \lim_{x \to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \leq 0 \\ \Rightarrow \dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} = 0$

Comment: regards. I may say that it is not finished yet. If you want to use sandwich theorem..then you must prove $ 0 \le \lim \frac{f+g}{f^{2} + g^{2}} \le 0 $. This means $0 \le \lim \frac{f+g}{f^{2} + g^{2}}$ AND $  \lim \frac{f+g}{f^{2} + g^{2}} \le 0$

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how you conclude $\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} = 0$ from $\lim_{x \to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \geq 0$.

In any case, the proof can be simplified. Write

$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}= \lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} + \dfrac{g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}
$$

Since $f^2(x), g^2(x) \geq 0$, we have

$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} +  \dfrac{g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \leq \lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x)}{f^2(x)} +  \dfrac{g(x)}{g^2(x)} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{1}{f(x)} +  \dfrac{1}{g(x)} =0
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\bigg|\dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f(x)^2+g(x)^2}\bigg|=\bigg|\dfrac{r(x)\big(\cos \theta(x)+\sin\theta(x)\big)}{r(x)^2}\bigg|\le\dfrac{2}{r(x)}\to 0$

Since $r(x)=\sqrt{f(x)^2+g(x)^2}\to+\infty$

Answer (score 0):

For $x>0$ and $y>0$ we have, 
$$\color{blue}{x+y+\frac{y^2}{x} +\frac{x^2}{y}  =(x^2 +y^2)(\frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{y}) \ge x+y  \implies \frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2} \le \frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{y}}$$
Hence, since $f(x)>0, g(x)>0$  for $x$ evry closed to $x_0$ we have
$$0 \le \lim_{x \to x_0} \dfrac{f(x)+g(x)}{f^2(x)+g^2(x)} \le \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{1}{f(x)} +  \frac{1}{g(x)} =0$$